# Bugzilla: redirecting to external website

Tags: apache-2.2, bugzilla

I just did a fresh install of CentOS 7 on a server and I am running into a problem with getting a web application up and running.

I am working on installing Bugzilla and I am struggling at the very end.

I have used this guide to help me out: http://blog.hyperexpert.com/how-to-install-the-latest-bugzilla-on-centos/

Looking at my history, for some reason I ran the following while trying to troubleshoot something: $ wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/

Now, I get directed to the following page after navigating to http://localhost/bugzilla

[image: oh no!]

I am lost at this point. I am pretty sure running the mentioned command above is related to this redirect. However, it is beyond my current knowledge and I have gotten nowhere on my own for a couple days now.

Comment: Go into the directory you were when you ran the wget command and delete the index.html file.

Comment: @yoonix You may as well just make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the directory you were when you ran the wget command and delete the index.html file.

Comment: And then you'll need to reinstate the original one from the Bugzilla tarball.

Comment: No you don't.  The original one is called index.cgi and should still be there.

Comment: You're quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would make more sense to actually follow the official Bugzilla project instructions? :-)

http://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/index.html

Comment: @Gervase Markham As someone that is new to this realm, the Bugzilla instructions were a bit sparse IMO.

Comment: I am happy to expand them, if you have feedback that's a bit more specific :-) 

@yoonix:
`gerv@hare:/tmp$ git clone https://git.mozilla.org/bugzilla/bugzilla`
`Cloning into 'bugzilla'...`
`remote: Counting objects: 94413, done.`
`...`

Comment: You're right.  I hit the url with a browser and got a 404 but it works fine with git.  Removed that comment.